# I have a question about the identity matrix $I$ being similar to only $I$ (linear algebra, hoffman kunze)

Tags: linear-algebra

$Recall$ square matrices $A$,$B$ are $similar$ if there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that $A$=$P^{-1}BP$

$Recall$ Let $T$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and let $B,B'$ be ordered bases for $V$. then if $[T]_B$,$[T]_{B'}$ are the matrices of $T$ in ordered bases $B,B'$ respectively, these two matrices are similar.

$My$ $Idea$

When $T$ is the identity operator on $V=R^2$ and $B$ is the standard basis {$e_1$,$e_2$} for $R^2$ and $B'$={$e_2,e_1$}, $[T]_B$ is the identity matrix $I$ and $[T]_{B'}$=$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

By the second $Recall$, these two matrices are similar. But they can not be similar ! Because if some matrix $A$ is similar to the identity matrix $I$ then $A$=$I$ by the first $Recall$

$Question$

Am I wrong about the definition of ordered basis?  I don't know where the error is. I got this question while I was looking at the Exercise 11 of sec5.3 in Linear hoffman kunze. If this error is true , the determinant value $detT$ for linear operator $T$ is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Te_2 = e_2 = 1e_2+0e_1$ and $Te_1 = e_1 = 0e_2+1e_1$, then $[T]_{B'}$ is also the identity matrix. Indeed, for any ordered basis $C$ for $\mathbb R^2$ we have that $[T]_C$ is the identity matrix.